# Android layout get compressed if keyboard is visible

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an Android Layout with Xamarin.
When the keyboard is visible, the layout is compressed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="20"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/faded_div"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/div1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="16"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/div2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Common.Droid.UI.Controls.NXButton
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Aplicar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The goal is for the keyboard to overlay the layout.

How can I prevent the screen from moving when the keyboard is visible? 
Can you help me?

Comment: Actually I'm using the weight property of LinearLayout to divide the layout.
It looks that when the keyboard appears the weight sum its equal to the available screen and not the entire display.

Comment: Can you post your code? If you do not post related code, we cannot guess what is your layout.

Comment: there u have it

Comment: Do you have a edittext in the `Common.Droid.UI.Controls.NXButton`? If the keyboard is visible, make the above layout cannot be compressed and edittext could be seen, you should add `WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan` in `[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true,WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it

```
<activity android:name=".UserRegistration"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
```

Tell me the result after the test

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, Actually I'm using the weight property of LinearLayout to divide the layout. It looks that when the keyboard appears the weight sum its equal to the available screen and not the entire display.

Answer (score 0):

in `xamarin native andorid` use this syntax code on your `Activity` for prevent the screen moving:

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustNothing);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, Actually I'm using the weight property of LinearLayout to divide the layout. It looks that when the keyboard appears the weight sum its equal to the available screen and not the entire display.

Comment: can you send your xml code to my email address? maybe i can help you

Comment: your layout is not complete, plz send your complete layout